# How to handle upvoted bad questions

Tags: discussion, downvotes, upvotes, bad-questions

Sometimes on Stack Overflow, there are questions that show no effort or research but are on a very popular topic and get many upvotes.

For example, "I don't know how to do [something], nothing works, please give me example code on how to do it."
The upvote arrow says "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear". This question only barely matches the "usefulness" part.

But, sometimes these questions get upvoted a lot because people have similar questions.

**What should I do with these questions?**

Should I downvote them because they "show no research effort"?
I feel that if I upvote this question, even though it is sometimes useful to me, this will promote questions like that. What would the Stack Overflow community recommend doing? Currently, I don't upvote or downvote these questions. What would be recommended?

Comment: flag to close it

Comment: I always wondered if _"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"_ is meant to be &&ed or ||ed... :)

Comment: @matiash I would say `&&` for the upvote hovertext but `||` for the downvote hovertext.

Comment: What are && and || in this context?

Comment: @Thomas **&&** is the Java/JavaScript/Swift **AND** operator; **||** is **OR**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is simple.  Treat it the exact same way that you would treat a brand new question with no votes at all.  Downvote if you think it's a bad question, and close if you think that it's off topic, a duplicate, or otherwise not worth answering.  Just like you would with a new question, and even upvote it if it's clearly written and useful.

And if the question remains upvoted and open, and you can't convince a moderator to close it, than you're just going to have to live with the fact that you're not the sole decider of quality around here, and that more people disagree with you about the question than agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

Edit them if they can be salvaged.

If it's a bad question on a good topic, then make it a good post on a good topic *if you can*. Obviously, you can't fix every post, and you certainly don't have to.

Everyone (including you) is free to vote as they please, and votes can carry different meanings based on their context.

If the question is *so bad* that it cannot be saved by any amount of editing and it still gets upvotes, it's likely that it is on an interesting or perplexing topic. Often, these questions are either 1) difficult to answer or 2) carry a highly upvoted answer that provides an excellent solution to the problem (or both).

As you said yourself, the hover text is important (emphasis mine):

> This question shows research effort; it is **useful** and clear.

Sometimes, highly upvoted questions are neither researched nor clear, but if they are *interesting* or bring up a common issue, they will be upvoted because they are **useful**, which is also a part of the hover text.

So, should you upvote them? Well, again, that's [up to you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). If you're unsure, just do as you've been doing and move on: the community will handle them as it sees fit through closing, editing, or deletion if need be.